# problem deploying dotnet cloud function GCP

Tags: .net-core, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a .NET Core 3.1 cloud function (zipped source code on Cloud Storage Bucket), last time I successfully deployed it a month ago. Now I did a minor code change, zipped the source code and wanted to deploy a new version of it I get the following error:

`Deployment failure: Build failed: Failed to run /bin/build: runtimeconfig.json does not exist; Error ID: 6b309792`

It's really weird, I also tried to deploy the same source code that worked before and got the same error... What's the reason and how to fix it?

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that this function consists of a few projects in the following structure:

src
-my-function
-referenced_solution
--project1
--project2
--project3

To let GCP understand the structure I used GOOGLE_BUILDABLE="./my-function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimentation I changed var GOOGLE_BUILDABLE to just "my-function" and that fixed the problem. Still strange that it used to work fine with "./my-function"